# ZF2 dynamic Route Check against 1000 entries within the database

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework2

At the moment it is only a idea but I want to know whether it is possible or not or you have a better idea? I have about 1000 cities in my database and need to include this in my router check.

I know there are literal, segement and regex checks. How can include this cities within my Router?

At the moment my router looks like this, but like you see its more than a wildecard/test check.

```
'city' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/[:city]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'state' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'action' => 'city'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Instead of checking your cities validity in the router, have you considered checking their validity in your module's pre-dispatch event? You will have access to the route there, and be able to match it against the DB and direct them elsewhere if needed from there.

Comment: Thanx Mikey, no i dont have considered it because of i dont know it. If its not to much, could you please provide me an example how i can implement it?

Comment: Hello Mikey, i want to thank you. Have now found a solution because of your comment. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! You should post your solution below and mark it accepted so others can share the knowledge!